# R: How to aggregate with NA values

Tags: r

To give a small working example, suppose I have the following data frame:

```
library(dplyr)
country <- rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 6)
year <- rep(c(1,2,3), each = 2, times = 3)
categ <- rep(c(0,1), times = 9)
pop <- rep(c(NA, runif(n=8)), each=2)
money <- runif(18)+100

df <- data.frame(Country = country, 
                 Year = year, 
                 Category = categ, 
                 Population = pop, 
                 Money = money)
```

Now the data I'm actually working with has many more repetitions, namely for every country, year, and category, there are many repeated rows corresponding to various sources of money, and I want to sum these all together.  However, for now it's enough just to have one row for each country, year, and category, and just trivially apply the `sum()` function on each row.  This will still exhibit the behavior I'm trying to get rid of.

Notice that for country A in year 1, the population listed is `NA`.  Therefore when I run

```
aggregate(Money ~ Country+Year+Category+Population, df, sum)
```

the resulting data frame has dropped the rows corresponding to country A and year 1.  I'm only using the `...+Population...` bit of code because I want the output data frame to retain this column.

I'm wondering how to make the `aggregate()` function not drop things that have `NA`s in the columns by which the grouping occurs--it'd be nice if, for instance, the `NA`s themselves could be treated as values to group by.

**My attempts**: I tried turning the Population column into factors but that didn't change the behavior.  I read something on the `na.action` argument but neither `na.action=NULL` nor `na.action=na.skip` changed the behavior.  I thought about trying to turn all the `NA`s to 0s, and I can't think of what that would hurt but it feels like a hack that might bite me later on--not sure.  But if I try to do it, I'm not sure how I would.  When I wrote a function with the `is.na()` function in it, it didn't apply the `if (is.na(x))` test in a vectorized way and gave the error that it would just use the first element of the vector.  I thought about perhaps using `lapply()` on the column and coercing it back to a vector and sticking that in the column, but that also sounds kind of hacky and needlessly round-about.

The solution here seemed to be about keeping the `NA` values out of the data frame in the first place, which I can't do: [Aggregate raster in R with NA values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23369579/aggregate-raster-in-r-with-na-values)

Comment: You should check `addNA`. [Allow grouping with NA in aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30996273/allow-grouping-with-na-in-aggregate-function)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have already mentioned `dplyr` before your data, you can use `dplyr::summarise` function. The `summarise` function supports grouping on `NA` values.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Country,Year,Category,Population) %>%
  summarise(Money = sum(Money))

# # A tibble: 18 x 5
# # Groups: Country, Year, Category [?]
# Country  Year Category Population Money
# <fctr>  <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 A        1.00     0        NA       101
# 2 A        1.00     1.00     NA       100
# 3 A        2.00     0         0.482   101
# 4 A        2.00     1.00      0.482   101
# 5 A        3.00     0         0.600   101
# 6 A        3.00     1.00      0.600   101
# 7 B        1.00     0         0.494   101
# 8 B        1.00     1.00      0.494   101
# 9 B        2.00     0         0.186   100
# 10 B        2.00     1.00      0.186   100
# 11 B        3.00     0         0.827   101
# 12 B        3.00     1.00      0.827   101
# 13 C        1.00     0         0.668   100
# 14 C        1.00     1.00      0.668   101
# 15 C        2.00     0         0.794   100
# 16 C        2.00     1.00      0.794   100
# 17 C        3.00     0         0.108   100
# 18 C        3.00     1.00      0.108   100
```

**Note:** The OP's sample data doesn't have multiple rows for same groups. Hence, number of summarized rows will be same as actual rows.